# get text part upto a specific tag in xpath

Tags: html, web-scraping, xpath, web-crawler

i am trying to get text till 1st <.hr>(ignore dot) tag using Xpath

```
<div class="entry">
   <p> some text</p>
   <p> some text2</p>
   <p> some text3</p>
   <p> some text4</p>
   <hr>(get text part before this hr tag)
   <p> some text5</p>
   <hr>
   <p> some text6</p>
</div>
```

tried this

```
//hr[1]/ancestor::div[@class="entry"]/text()
```

and some similar variants but couldn't get the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines will give you the set of nodes before the `hr` node

```
//div[@class="entry"]/*[not(preceding-sibling::hr | self::hr)]
```

It will list those nodes that

- are children of the div with class name "entry",
- are not preceded by a node named hr and
- are not themselves a `hr` node

Comment: thanks a lot man was struggling for a few hours on this.